# JNI Compile error with __THROW

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, java-native-interface, throw

When I compile a JNI Code by c compiler, the following error message is displayed.
It is ok when I compile this code on the linux c compiler.

```
/usr/include/glob.h:148:32: error : expected function body after function declarator
glob_t *__restrict __pglob) __THROW;
```

How can I erase this compile error?

Comment: What compiler do you use? And on which enviroment? glob is a Posix specific thing.